# Rounding to tens in Java formula doesn't make sense

Tags: java

I found this formula on SO but I don't get how it works:

```
(n + 5) / 10 * 10
```

This rounds a number to the multiple of ten but when I calculate it it just divides and multiplies back to n+5. How does this actually work?

Example (in Java):

```
(24 + 5) / 10 * 10 = 20
```

While it should actually be 29 as far as I know.

Comment: Order of execution is left to right. What does `29/10` give in integer division?

Comment: Result will be 29 if you use a double.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing these operations on `int`. That's why, every operation result is also an `int`. What happens is:

`(24 + 5) = 29`

`29 / 10 = 2` (because the fraction part is always dropped in ints)

`2 * 10 = 20`

This rounding method works fine only for `float` and `double`. You can try to cast the `int` to `double`.